# WP7 RootFrame_NavigationFailed

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

I made a fresh Project in WP7 and I moved the Default page called MainPage.xaml to a sub folder and renamed it to Main.xaml.

I then went to WMAppManifest.xaml and I changed the Default Task property to:

```
<DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="MyProj\Central\UI\Main.xaml"/>
```

Where MyProj is the name of the project, Central and UI are folders. This however throws an exception and states that the app has failed to navigate upon launching the application.

How do I fix this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `MyProj\` bit at the start of the path - assuming that the Central is a directory straight off the root of the project.